# How can I extract results of aggregate queries in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I am simply trying to check if any rows that meet certain conditions exist:

```
  // Method defined on type T
  def exists(some_data : Long, other_data : Long) : Boolean = DB.withSession { implicit session : Session =>
    (for {
      row <- table // table is a Table[T]
      if row.some_data =!= some_data
      if row.other_data === other_data 
    } yield row).length > 0
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [R]scala.slick.lifted.Column[R]
[error]  required: Boolean
```

Any idea what is going on? For now I am just turning the results into a scala list (instead of `.length` I have `.list.length`) and checking the length of that, but I should not have to do that. I could not find any methods on columns to help me extract the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `.length.run`

`.length` [returns a Column[Int]](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/a8608e2b6d7ccebead8656f2295454bff4bdc5e1/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala#L136), which is [implictly converted to an Executor](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/a8608e2b6d7ccebead8656f2295454bff4bdc5e1/src/main/scala/scala/slick/profile/BasicProfile.scala#L48) when you call [the method `.run`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/a8608e2b6d7ccebead8656f2295454bff4bdc5e1/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/JdbcExecutorComponent.scala#L21)