# Slick 2 aggregation - how to get a scalar result?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I have a table with an `Int` column `TIME` in it:

```
def time = column[Int]("TIME")
```

The [table is mapped](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/schemas.html#mapped-tables) to a custom type. I want to find a maximum time value, i.e. to perform a simple aggregation. [The example in the documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/queries.html#aggregation) seems easy enough:

```
val q = coffees.map(_.price)
val q1 = q.min
val q2 = q.max
```

However, when I do this, the type of q1 and q2 is `Column[Option[Int]]`. I can perform a `get` or `getOrElse` on this to get a result of type `Column[Int]` (even this seems somewhat surprising to me - is `get` a member of `Column`, or is the value converted from `Option[Int]` to `Int` and then wrapped to Column again? Why?), but I am unable to use the scalar value, when I attempt to assign it to Int, I get an error message saying:

> ```
> type mismatch;
>  found   : scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int]
>  required: Int
> ```

How can I get the scala value from the aggregated query?

Comment: Following questions seems to be solving the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516057/count-in-slick-2-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277958/how-can-i-extract-results-of-aggregate-queries-in-slick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are not calling the invoker that's the reason why you get a `Column` object. Try this:

```
val q1 = q.min.run
```

Should return an `Option[Int]` and then you can `get` or `getOrElse`.

Comment: Great. run is what I was missing. I was trying list or first, like in normal queries, but that did not work. Still, run seems to be returning Option[Int], therefore run.get or run.getOrElse seems to be necessary.

Comment: Ah right, it depends if your column is nullable the query returns an `Option`, if not you get directly the value, in your case probably it is nullable and you need to `get` or `getOrElse`, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I do not think my column is nullable (def added into the question). Perhaps the aggregation needs to cope with a situation there are no records at all, in which case there can be no aggregate?

Comment: Exactly. That's the reason Suma!

Comment: @Suma thanks for the edit, had to go away from keyboard.